# Not sure why I'm getting a TypeError

Tags: python, typeerror

```
num_trades = int(input("Number of trades for today? "))
for i in range(1, num_trades + 1):
    print()
    action = input("Trade number", i, "(buy/sell)? ")
    num_shares = int(input("Number of shares to buy? "))
```

I'm getting a `TypeError` on the line,`"action = input("Trade number", i, "(buy/sell)? ")"`

This error message says "`TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3`"

Don't know what it means and don't know how to correct. Help

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You are passing 3 arguments to `input()`:

```
action = input("Trade number", i, "(buy/sell)? ")
```

and it only takes one; only `print()` takes multiple arguments. Use string formatting:

```
action = input("Trade number {} (buy/sell)? ".format(i))
```

or use string concatenation:

```
action = input("Trade number " + str(i) + " (buy/sell)? ")
```

but that requires you to turn `i` into a string explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're calling input with 3 arguments

use

```
input("Trade number " + str(i) + " (buy/sell?")
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you *exactly* what is wrong. The [`input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) function expects one argument, but you gave it three.

Instead of

```
input("Trade number", i, "(buy/sell)? ")
```

Try

```
input("Trade number " + str(i) + " (buy/sell)? ")
```

You're probably confused, because you can `print` multiple things, by separating them with commas, but 99% of the places, that won't work.  `input` expects you to give it one string argument, and by placing commas there, you've given it three arguments. My suggestion concatenated those three strings into one, which we passed to `input`.

Answer (score 0):

the function is taking just one argument, not 3. Did you mean:

```
num_trades = int(input("Number of trades for today? "))
for i in range(1, num_trades + 1):
print()
action = input("Trade number " + str(i) + " (buy/sell)? ")
num_shares = int(input("Number of shares to buy? "))
```